# How to update Animated.Value to change without animation?

Tags: react-native

I sometimes want to change `Animated.Value` without any interpolation, is there a way to do that without using something like this.

```
const value = new Animated.Value(X);
Animated.timing(value, {toValue: Y, duration: 0})
```

Answer (score 4):

In case someone read this, you can use the method setValue as per [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animatedvalue#setvalue) :

```
YourAnimatedValue.setValue(number)
```

so in your example it will be:

```
value.setValue(Y)
```

Comment: Done :) Hope it is better now